# Use InAppBrowser for google map branding on phone gap app

Tags: google-maps, cordova, maps, inappbrowser

I have made a phone gap application that includes a google map. When you tap the branding/terms of use the links open filling the screen so its not possible to go back to the app.

Is it possible to link these to an in app browser like other URLs?

Comment: I think there should be a setting in the phonegap, to open links in default web browser. This might be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011753/phonegap-open-external-link-in-default-browser-outside-the-app

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have tried similar things to this with no success. 

I assume the issue is that the links are built into the google map API so i ant put classes on them to link to any jQuery