# <access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes" /> not working for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

launch-external does not seems to work for iOS. but it works perfectly for android.

I am looking for a 'launch-external' equivalent for iOS, i am using cardova (version 3.7.0) and phoneGap online build tool.

below is my config.xml

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.something.something" version="1.0.3">
  <name>something</name>
  <description>
something
  </description>
  <author href="http://something.com" email="something@something.com">Something</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>

  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>  
    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

  <!-- Settings Icon -->
  <!--
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
  -->
  <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
  <!--
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
  -->

  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
  </platform>


  <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
  <access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes" />


  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

I am using location.href in index.html to open the url in separte browser. This is working in Android as expected but not in iOS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30397786/2769095 this may be helpful. I used something similar and it worked very well

Comment: thanks @Oliver. But i am not using cardova CLI for build, instead using phoneGap online build. Hence i do not have access to the .m files. I was hoping this to be much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html), `launch-external` is only mentioned in the Android section. That's probably why it doesn't work for iOS.

As an alternative, you could use the [InAppBrowser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) (don't be fooled by its name) to open certain links externally, but this requires you to rewrite those links to `window.open` calls, with the `target` parameter set to `_system`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i am looking for an app level solution and not just for some hand picked links. So i am looking for something at app configuration level.

Comment: I don't think there is an app level solution other than using inAppBrowser plugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these suggestions in a recent iOS build and the only thing that worked for me was the InAppBrowser plugin and changing the code to window.open(href,"_system");