# Ionic 4 - How to open URL in web browser instead of webview in app on Android App?

Tags: android, ionic4, capacitor

How to open URL in a web browser instead of webview in-app on Android App?

I used,

```
<ion-button  href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverFlow</ion-button>
```

The URL is opening in the in-app browser, I need to open an android system's default browser.

I have gone through the official document, I couldn't find useless information from there.

1. https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api
2. https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/components#button
3. https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button/

Comment: check this ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562745/ionic-application-open-link-in-system-browser

Answer (score 4):

You want to read the cordova documentation it can b help you to find your solution.

_self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise, it opens in the InAppBrowser.
_blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
_system: Opens in the system's web browser.

Cordova
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html

Ionic 4
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Answer (score 3):

#### Capacitor

To programmatically open URLs (for example by binding to a `(click)` event of a button or link) in [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) you can use this:

**Open externally:**

Capacitor V2: Use the App API (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app) where you have a method `canOpenUrl(…)` and a method `openUrl(…)`.

Capacitor V3: Use the AppLauncher API (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/app-launcher) where you have a method `canOpenUrl(…)` and a method `openUrl(…)`.

**Open in in-app browser:**

If you want to open an URL in a so called *in-app browser* you can use the Browser API (`@capacitor/browser` plugin):

- Capacitor 2: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser
- Capacitor 3 (soon to be released): https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/browser

On Android this opens a [Chrome WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/webview/overview/), on iOS a [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller), so the user "kind of" stays in the app.

Comment: Don't forget to add "http://" or "https://" otherwise the plugin won't open the site.