# Cordova : Open a link using Google Chrome

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

I would like to open a link using Google Chrome (not another browser) from my Cordova application. I tried several solutions but nothing works.

First, I tried to create a link to `googlechrome://` (using a HTML `<a>` tag). It opens Google Chrome, but I can't choose what URL to open.

Then, I tried to create a link to `intent://my.url.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end`. This link works when I open it from a browser (like Firefox or Google Chrome), but it doesn't work when I open it from my Cordova app.

I also tried to use the [cordova-webintent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) plugin, like that :

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
    {
        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
        url: 'intent://my.url.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end'
    },
    function() {
        alert(url);
    },
    function(){
        alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent');
    }
);
```

But I get a *"Failed to open URL via Android Intent"* error.

What should I do ?

PS : I wrote `<allow-intent href="*" />` in my config.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I just had to create a link like this one :

```html
<a href="googlechrome://navigate?url=https://my.url.com/"></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](http://cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) with `_system` as target:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Or you can use [cordova-plugin-webintent2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-webintent2) (don't know if this is the same you are using), like this:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
        url:  "googlechrome://navigate?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    },
    function() {},
    function() {
        alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
      console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent.")
    });
```

The url must start with http or https, it does not allow relative urls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first solution does not work, because it asks the user what browser to choose, and that's not what I want. However, the snippet you posted helped me to understand the undocumented `googlechrome://` URL Scheme, and I found a simple solution using it (see my answer). Thanks !

Comment: I gave you the bounty because you helped me a lot to find the answer :)

Comment: If its a google map link, that you want to force using chrome vs maps app, the above `InAppBrowser` option won't work.  The phone will prompt the user if they want to use Maps or Chrome to open the link - of if the user has already defaulted to Maps, it will simply bypass the question and auto-open in Maps - defeating the purpose of forcing to open in chrome.