# Google map V3 in phone gap loads map.google.com page

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

In my phone-gap app I have loaded a page with google map V3. its  showing properly. but when I touch the map or try to move the marker totally unload the whole index.html and moves to map.google.com  then only option left for me is to kill the application.

Comment: There are some ugly minded people in stackoverflow team, they simply, press -1 button. this is really annoying, when I know my questions are genuine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem too...  it turned out that my users were inadvertently clicking on the Google icon (bottom left corner of map) or Terms and Conditions (bottom right corner of map).  These link out to google sites and pop the session away from index.html (and the phonegap/cordova javascript context).

If that's what you're running into, check out this link ([Cordova Phonegap and Google Maps v3 javascript api: How to add backbutton functionality when clicking either the license link or the Google maps logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355842/cordova-phonegap-and-google-maps-v3-javascript-api-how-to-add-backbutton-functi)) with a few ideas on how to gracefully handle this issue.